# How do you allow your clients to administer their apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Nearly finished with a clothes shopping app and I'm thinking about the best way to allow the owners of the app to manage items for sale.

In a previous app I built there was a section of the app that had an administration button that opened up a username and password page that gave the way app owners access to an administration area. I didn't like this approach.

Another approach would be to give them access to parse.com (I used them for the backend database). This way they can directly manipulate data. Although there is more chance of them messing things up.

I'd like to hear how those who have experience in iOS development and publishing apps dealt with these types of situations.

Thanks for your time.

Hopefully this is a valid question. If not where do I post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `CMS` (Content Management System). This is a layer you add on top of you web service (in your case, parse) to allow the app owner to modify the data in a safe environment (typically a web site) that will not allow him to mess up the data as you will dictate the rule of data entry.

If you have basic knowledge in PHP, this is not that hard to make and the benefit of having a CMS is well worth the time spent on building it.

Comment: I'm from a ruby/ruby on rails background but know a little PHP. So you're saying don't give direct access to parse.com directly? (a parse.com account created for the client)   I was thinking a CMS would be the way but was trying to avoid extra work.

Comment: Well, if you give the access to parse directly to your client, there is always a risk he screws things up and you will have to make extra work to salvage the database. After a while building CMS, this will become pretty easy for you and you can even charge it to your clients.  If you hope to build professional apps, this is the way to go (in my own opinion). Regarding the technologie used to make the CMS, I was stating PHP because it's pretty easy, but there is an infinity of technology you can work with.